# How to add stage-snaps from different confinements?

Tags: snapcraft

I'm trying to use these :

```
stage-snaps:
  - ipfs/edge
  - ipfs-cluster/edge
```

However, one is strict, and the other is classic.

> Failed to install or refresh a snap: 'ipfs-cluster' does not exist or is not available on the desired channel 'edge'. Use `snap info ipfs-cluster` to get a list of channels the snap is available on.

Changing the confinement changes the error.

> Failed to install or refresh a snap: 'ipfs' does not exist or is not available on the desired channel 'edge'. Use `snap info ipfs` to get a list of channels the snap is available on.

So... How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's by using "full channel names".

```
stage-snaps:
  - ipfs/latest/edge
  - ipfs-cluster/latest/edge
```

Yay for undocumented specs.